# Accessing function defined within function in swift

Tags: function, swift

Say I have a class **NamedShape** defined like this:

```
class NamedShape {
    var numberOfSides: Int = 0
    var name: String

    init(name: String) {
      self.name = name
    }

    func simpleDescription() -> String {
       return "A shape with \(numberOfSides) sides."
    }

    func containerFunc() -> Void{
        println("strange world")

        func subFunc() -> String {
            return "sub function returns string"
        }

        println(subFunc())

    }
}
```

I can initialize it like this:

```
let someNamedShape = NamedShape(name:"polynomial")
```

And invoke some method like this:

```
someNamedShape.containerFunc()
```

Now how can I invoke method **subFunc** within **containerFunc** on its object?

Compiler complains while trying this:

```
someNamedShape.containerFunc().subFunc()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like it's not possible, unless you return the inner function from its containing function. Here's what the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-XID_202) says

> Nested functions are hidden from the outside world by default, but can still be called and used by their enclosing function. An enclosing function can also return one of its nested functions to allow the nested function to be used in another scope.

This is how your code should look like in order to be able to call the subfunc

```
class NamedShape {
    var numberOfSides: Int = 0
    var name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    func simpleDescription() -> String {
        return "A shape with \(numberOfSides) sides."
    }

    func containerFunc() -> (() -> String) {
        println("strange world")

        func subFunc() -> String {
            return "sub function returns string"
        }

        println(subFunc())

        return subFunc
    }
}

let someNamedShape = NamedShape(name:"polynomial")
let subfunc = someNamedShape.containerFunc()
subfunc()
```

Comment: So I take it that a function nested inside a method is always a function and never a method, yes?

Comment: Yes. Think of it as a closure: you can use in the function/method where it is defined, and its enclosing function/method can return it, but the closure itself is not visible outside, just like any other local variable.

Comment: Uh, if a nested function is always a function and never a method, why do you call it a "function/method"? (Kind of wishing Swift had used different keywords for methods and properties.)

Comment: by function/method I am referring to the container of the nested function